# How do I inject code into an iOS process

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, code-injection

#### Question:

Looking at: https://github.com/Flipboard/FLEX I see a screenshot of the framework being used on the Apple Springboard with a caption that reads:

> The code injection is left as an exercise for the reader.

I'm not directly interested in injecting it into the Springboard, but if I did want to inject the framework into another process (like the Calculator app for instance), how would I go about doing so?

As a side-note, I am willing to jailbreak my device if that's the only way of doing something like this.

#### What I've tried:

- I've tried using: https://github.com/DyCI/dyci-main to inject apps that I had the source to, but I couldn't run it on my device, and I also couldn't run it on apps I didn't have the source to
- I've also tried using: https://github.com/johnno1962/injectionforxcode but I kept getting provisioning errors during the injecting process

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I Tweeted to Ryan Olson (according to the Git blame log he posted the picture) and got this reply: https://twitter.com/ryanolsonk/status/580011917491601408

It looks like it is necessary to Jailbreak for this.

After doing more research I found a tool called "Cycript" by Jay Freeman (Saurik).
If you're interested in remote injection on a live application: take a look at: http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/ios-application-security-part-1-setting-up-a-mobile-pentesting-platform/

If you're unfamiliar with MobileSubstrate and Theos, you should definitely take a look:
http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Theos/Setup

Comment: This is correct. You need to be on a jailbroken device.